# Reading multiline json using Spark Dataset API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I would like to perform join on two datasets using `join()` method. But I am unable to understand how the condition or the join column name needs to be specified.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                  .master("spark://10.127.153.198:7077")
                  .getOrCreate();

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("partyId");

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().text("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\alert.json");
        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().text("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\contract.json");

        df.join(df2,JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(list)).show();


//      df.join(df2, "partyId").show();

    }
```

When I execute the above code, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `partyId` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [value];
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90$$anonfun$apply$56.apply(Analyzer.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90$$anonfun$apply$56.apply(Analyzer.scala:1977)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90.apply(Analyzer.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$90.apply(Analyzer.scala:1975)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$commonNaturalJoinProcessing(Analyzer.scala:1975)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$$anonfun$apply$31.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1961)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$$anonfun$apply$31.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveNaturalAndUsingJoin$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1957)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2822)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.join(Dataset.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.join(Dataset.scala:748)
    at com.cisco.cdx.batch.JsonDataReader.main(JsonDataReader.java:27)
```

Both the JSON's have the column "partyId". Please help.

Data:

Both the JSON's have the column "partyId". But, when I am joining both datasets spark is unable to find the column. Is there anything I am missing here?

Alerts.json

```
{
    "sourcePartyId": "SmartAccount_700001",
    "sourceSubPartyId": "",
    "partyId": "700001",
    "managedndjn": "BIZ_KEY_999001",
    "neAlert": {
        "data1": [{
            "sni": "c1f44bb6-e429-11e7-9afc-64609ee945d1",
                }],
        "daa2": [{
            "sni": "c1f44bb6-e429-11e7-9afc-64609ee945d1",
        }],
        "data3": [{
            "sni": "c1f44bb6-e429-11e7-9afc-64609ee945d1",
            "ndjn": "999001",
        }],
        "advisory": [{
            "sni": "c1f44bb6-e429-11e7-9afc-64609ee945d1",
            "ndjn": "999001",
        }]
    }
}
```

Contracts.json

```
{

  "sourceSubPartyId": "",
  "partyId": "700001",
  "neContract": {
    "serialNumber": "FCH2013V245",
    "productId": "FS4000-K9",
    "coverageInfo": [
      {
        "billToCity": "Delhi",
        "billToCountry": "India",
        "billToPostalCode": "260001",
        "billToProvince": "",
        "slaCode": "1234",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, when i am reading the below way i am able to print the data.

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> javaRDD = spark.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles("C:\\\\Users\\\\phyadavi\\\\LearningAndDevelopment\\\\Spark-Demo\\\\data1\\\\alert.json", 1).toJavaRDD();
List<Tuple2<String, String>> collect = javaRDD.collect();
        collect.forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(x._1);
            System.out.println(x._2);
        });
```

Comment: can you share the schema of both dataframe `df` and `df2`

Comment: In your json "C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\alert.json", partyId (join key) is not present. Cross verify schema and then decide your join key.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I have provided the schema as well as sample data.

Comment: have you tried with `df.join(df2,df("partyID") === df2("partyID")).show()`, I am not sure with the java but it works in scala and also with `Seq("partyID")`

Comment: @ShankarKoirala yes i tried using the java version of this df.join(df2, df.col("partyId"));  but i am still getting the same issue. The error says Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "partyId" among (value);

Comment: can you do df.printSchema() and same for df2 ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thanks for that. When i do a printSchema() i am getting this root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved after making the JSON single lined. Therefore i would like to post my answer.

```
public class JsonDataReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .master("spark://192.168.0.2:7077").getOrCreate();

//      JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> javaRDD = spark.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles("C:\\\\Users\\\\phyadavi\\\\LearningAndDevelopment\\\\Spark-Demo\\\\data1\\\\alert.json", 1).toJavaRDD();

        Seq<String> joinColumns = scala.collection.JavaConversions
                  .asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList("partyId","sourcePartyId", "sourceSubPartyId", "wfid", "generatedAt", "collectorId"));

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("multiLine",true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                .json("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\alert.json");
        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                .json("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\contract.json");

        Dataset<Row> finalDS = df.join(df2, joinColumns,"inner");
        finalDS.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\final.json");

//      List<Tuple2<String, String>> collect = javaRDD.collect();
//      collect.forEach(x -> {
//          System.out.println(x._1);
//          System.out.println(x._2);
//      });

    }

}
```

However, @ShankarKoiralas answer was more precise and worked for me. Hence, accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to read as a text file with `spark.read().text()`

If you want to read a `json` file directly to dataframe you need to use

```
spark.read().json()
```

If the data is multilined then you need to add option as

```
spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json()
```

That's why you are not able to access the columns in `join`

Another way is to read as text file and convert it to JSON

```
val jsonRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to json").map(x => x._2)

spark.sqlContext.read.json(jsonRDD)
    .show(false)
```

Comment: when i read with json() i am getting root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

Comment: But bot the jsons are valid.

Comment: yes, I tried that as well but still it gives corrupt _record  Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().option("multiline", "true").json("C:\\Users\\phyadavi\\LearningAndDevelopment\\Spark-Demo\\data1\\contract.json");

Comment: It is showing the same 

root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167634/discussion-between-dataenthusiast-and-shankar-koirala).

Comment: For Spark 2.1 users refer to my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504983/8574275