# Access Oozie Configuration in Spark program

Tags: scala, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have an environment variable saved in my `.bash_profile`. I am trying to access it via a Spark program using `sys.env()` method in Scala. When I don't have Oozie Scheduling, I am able to access the environment variable in Spark properly. However when I try to schedule my program using Oozie, the program throws an error that it could not read the env variable.

Here's my workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='Security-User-Management'>

    <start to='spark-node' />

    <action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="hdfs://<some hdfs url>/user/clsadmin/cmdw-security/cmdw-security-logs"/>
                <mkdir path="hdfs://<some hdfs url>/user/clsadmin/cmdw-security/cmdw-security-logs"/>
            </prepare>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>CMDW_CLOUD_USERNAME</name>
                    <value>abcd</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <name>CMDW-Security-User-Management</name>
            <class>custom.cmdwldap.executable.Test</class>
            <jar>hdfs://some hdfs url/user/clsadmin/security/Security.jar</jar>
            <arg>CMDW_CLOUD_USERNAME=abcd</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Workflow failed, error message:
            ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

How do I read the `configuration` in my Scala code..

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to run job in yarn-cluster mode from edge node. It won't be able to recognize those variables since the spark driver runs in the different datanode of the cluster whose .bash_profile might not have this variable declared. In the edge node .bash_profile has variables declared which is why job ran successfully when you tested script by running spark-submit with either local or yarn-client mode.

> Run from EdgeNode: spark-submit local ---> Job runs in edge node.
>
> Run from EdgeNode: spark-submit yarn-client ---> Job gets started with
>   driver in edge node and executors in cluster's data nodes.
>
> Run from EdgeNode: spark-submit yarn-cluster ---> Job gets started in
>   edge node, driver starts in one of the data nodes and executors start
>   in rest of data nodes.

2. Just like shell action, Oozie executes other actions in a different compute node(possibly one of the datanodes) in the Hadoop cluster other than the edge node. This concept becomes complex when you think of yarn-client and yarn-cluster. When run from Oozie job fails since variables are not in .bash_profile of data nodes.

> Run from Oozie spark action: spark-submit local ---> Job runs in one
>   of the data nodes locally.
>
> Run from Oozie spark action: spark-submit yarn-client ---> Job gets
>   started with driver in one of the data node and executors in rest of
>   cluster's data nodes.
>
> Run from Oozie spark action: spark-submit yarn-cluster ---> Job gets
>   started in one of the data nodes, driver starts in another data node
>   and executors start in rest of data nodes.

Refer :
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#ActionNodes

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

[Oozie > what is the difference between asynchronous actions and synchronous actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224114/oozie-what-is-the-difference-between-asynchronous-actions-and-synchronous-acti/34481536#34481536)

Comment: Ok. Leaving aside the environment variables part, I have given `property`ies inside `configuration`. Can't we read that inside our Spark program? If yes, then how?

Comment: See if this helps your need. one way is to use typesafe jar "typesafe-config-2.10.1.jar".
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966791/read-values-from-config-in-scala

and 
https://medium.com/@ramkarnani24/reading-configurations-in-scala-f987f839f54d